# Outgoing e-mail server from Safari / text document

Tags: macos, mail.app, safari, gmail

When I send/share a URL in Safari I want the default outgoing sender to be my gmail and not iCloud address.  How do I set that. Also when I'm in a text document and I want to share/email it, the default shows my iCloud email, but I want it to be gmail.  I know I can change the outgoing in the e-mail program, but I want it to be the default.

Inside the e-mail program gmail is set as the default outgoing server.  The problem arises only when I'm sending/e-mailing/sharing straight from Safari or a document on my MacBook Pro.  When the e-mail program comes up the @iCloud account is the default outgoing server.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using OSX 10.8, under Mail > Preferences > Composing, the drop-down menu for "Send new messages from" can be changed from the default "Account of selected mailbox" to the specific account you want (in your case, the Gmail account).